# Razor Page with dynamic form

Tags: dynamic, razor-pages, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

Having recently migrated from years of web forms, I’ve built numerous dot net core razor page apps - So I’m not a complete beginner but I am struggling to understand the best way to approach one particular scenario. I have a page that captures some header information but also needs to capture some additional data that is specific to the “type” of record being edited. In webforms I dynamically loaded a user control for the relevant type using a path name (the path name of the user control being linked to the type so the system knew what form to load). With user controls I could then handle the form submission which meant the logic could be completely different for each type/form. Whereas I can use view components to create the relevant UI in the same way in my razor pages app, I can’t then handle the post back from there. So what would be the best way to approach this in razor pages? To make matters more complex, the type (and thus the objet i want to capture) could be defined in a RCL (another project). Also the type needs to be defined in a database entry, so I need to be able to load it from a string. Whereas a standalone page for each type would be easy, the management of this data is on one place in the core system so I can’t have a different page for each one.

Comment: Could you use Partials perhaps? https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/partial-pages

Comment: Maybe you can refer to [view component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Comment: Partials and view components are fine for creating the UI but they can’t handle a request/post back